# Java Regex to validate String

Tags: java, regex

I have just bought a book on Regex to try and get my head around it but I'm still really struggling with it. I am trying to create a java regex that will satisfy a string configuration that can;

1. Can contain lowercase letters ([a-z])
2. Can contain commas (,) but only between words
3. Can contain colon (:) but must be separated by words or multiply (*)
4. Can contain hyphens (-) but must be separated by words
5. Can contain multiply (*) but if used it must be the only character before/between/after the colon
6. Cannot contain spaces, 'words' are delimitated by a hyphens (-) or commas (,) or colon (:) or the end of the string

So for example the following would be true:

1. foo:bar
2. foo-bar:foo
3. foo,bar:foo
4. foo-bar,foo:bar,foo-bar
5. foo:bar:foo,bar
6. *:foo
7. foo:*
8. `*:*:*`

But the following would be false:

1. foo :bar
2. ,foo:bar
3. foo-:bar
4. -foo:bar
5. foo,:bar-
6. foo:bar,
7. foo,*:bar
8. foo-*:bar

This is what I have so far:

```
^[a-z-]|*[:?][a-z-]|*[:?][a-z-]|*
```

Comment: Have you tried something to accomplish this?

Comment: Try something and post your trials, and we're here to help you.

Comment: converting my answer to comment as asked :  
 

this is not java code, but here is a web service where you can test your regexps online : http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html . it's a life saver. well at least it saves a lot of time.

Apart from your book, you should also have in mind the javadoc for the Pattern class : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex that will work for all your cases:

```
([a-z]+([,-][a-z]+)*|\*)(:([a-z]+)([,-][a-z]+)*|\*)*
```

Here is a detailed analysis:

One of the basic structures used to build complicated regular expressions like this is actually pretty simple, and has the form *`text`*`(`*`separator text`*`)*`.  A regex of that form will match:

- one *text*
- one *text*, a *separator*, and another *text*
- one *text*, a *separator*, another *text*, another *separator*, and yet another *text*
- or more, just add another *separator* and a *text* to the end.

So here is a breakdown of the code:

- `[a-z]+([,-][a-z]+)*` is an instance of the pattern I discussed above: the *text* here is `[a-z]+`, and the *separator* is `[,-]`.
- `([a-z]+([,-][a-z]+)*|\*)` allows an asterisk to be matched instead.
- `([a-z]+([,-][a-z]+)*|\*)(:([a-z]+([,-][a-z]+)*|\*))*` is another instance of the pattern I discussed above: the *text* is `([a-z]+([,-][a-z]+)*|\*)`, and the *separator* is `:`.

If you plan to use this as a component of an even larger regex, in which the group matches will be important, I would recommend making the internal parens non-grouping, and place grouping parens around the entire regex, like so:

```
((?:[a-z]+(?:[,-][a-z]+)*|\*)(?::([a-z]+)(?:[,-][a-z]+)*|\*)*)
```

Comment: Since the OP is learning regex, it would probably be beneficial to break this down and explain it's different components.

Comment: If you don't mind breaking it down that would be hugely helpfull

Comment: @RyanWH Finished breaking it down.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to break that down in such a constructive manner it was *extremely* useful. I did find however that your published solution did not quite work for a couple of reasons. The first is most likely a typo as it appears you have places one too many brackets at the start that is not matched by a closing bracket. The other was that the second instance of the pattern did not allow for '*'. Just incase you are interested I modified the brackets to match your explanation and now it works: `([a-z]+([,-][a-z]+)*|\\*)(:([a-z]+([,-][a-z]+))*|\\*)*`

Answer (score 2):

We rarely see here somebody who can define positive and negative test cases. That makes live really easier.

Here's my regex with a 95% solution:

- `"(([a-z]+|\\*)[:,-])*([a-z]+|\\*)"` (JAVA-Version)
- `(([a-z]+|\*)[:,-])*([a-z]+|\*)` (plain regex)

It simply differntiates between words (a-z or *) and separators (one of :-,) and it must contain at least one word and words must be separated by a separator. It works for the positive cases and for the negative cases except the last two negative ones.

One remark: Such a complex "syntax" would in real live be implemented with a grammer definition tool like ANTLR (or a few years ago with lex/yacc, flex/bison). Regex can do that but will not be easy to maintain.

Comment: +1 for mentioning ANTLR, I had never heard of it but I will investigate it as it looks generally interesting.